# Custom Union in Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I need to union these rows on two ids without using an `IEqualityComparer`, as those are not supported in LINQ to Entities.

In `result` I need every unique combination of `BizId` and `BazId`, with the value from `foos` if the id pair came from there, else the value should be zero. This is a greatly simplified example and in reality these tables are very large and these operations cannot be done in memory. Because of this, this query **needs to work with LINQ to Entities** so that it can be translated to valid SQL and execute on the database. I suspect this can be done with some combination of `where`, `join`, and `DefaultIfEmpty()` instead of the `Union` and `Distinct()` but I am at a loss for now.

```
var foos = from f in Context.Foos where f.isActive select new { BizId = f.bizId, BazId = f.BazId, Value = f.Value };
var bars = from b in Context.Bars where b.isEnabled select new { BizId = b.bizId, BazId = b.BazId, Value = 0 };
var result = foos.Union(bars).Distinct(); //I need this to compare only BizId and BazId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by the two fields and then get the first item of each group:

```
foos.Union(bars).GroupBy(x => new { x.bizId, x.bazId })
    .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the foos will always be first in the list or should that be checked? I think this will work!

Comment: You should add `g.OrderBy(x => x....).FirstOrDefault()` if you want a specific item to be on top.

Comment: As per the question, I need the Value if it exists. To get this I modified your query a little bit: `foos.Union(bars).GroupBy(x => new { x.bizId, x.bazId }).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Allocation).FirstOrDefault())`. Thanks a lot!